# ehCache configuration for disk storage not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I cant get my ehCache working with diskStorage. I want a persistent cache that exists after i restart my app.
So i tried ehCache and this is my ehCache configuration file:

```
<diskStore path="C:\Temp\ehCache"/>  
<cache 
    name="testCache"  
    eternal="true"
    maxElementsInMemory="0"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="true"        
    >
</cache>
```

The cache works as long i dont restart the app. After i restart the app and ehCache is trying to load data from the cache files, i get this error:

```
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Faulting from repository failed
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.throwOrReturn(OnHeapCachingTier.java:350) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.fail(OnHeapCachingTier.java:361) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:337) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.access$200(OnHeapCachingTier.java:312) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:176) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.get(CacheStore.java:192) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1749) ~[ehcache-2.10.6.jar:2.10.6]
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.lookup(EhCacheCache.java:162) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(EhCacheCache.java:71) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:519) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:259) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:163) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232] 
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2958) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1738) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
...
...
```

I've tried different configuration variants, eg programmatically configuration or the xml config tag:

```
<persistence strategy="localRestartable" synchronousWrites="true"/>
```

but if i'm not using the config i posted above i always get the error:

> Cache testCache cannot be configured because the enterprise features manager could not be found. You must use an enterprise version of Ehcache to successfully enable enterprise persistence.

Does anyone know of athis problem?

Libs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

I also have a ShutdownListener to shutdown the CacheManager

```
 public class SpringEhcacheShutdownListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextClosedEvent) {
            CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown();      
        }
    }
}
```

This is my service method

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "testCache", key = "{ #root.methodName, #collectiveNr }" )
public org.wc3.Document getVCXml(String collectiveNr, Session session) throws ServiceException { ...}
```

Comment: I think you are using wrong library, please show the full pom file with spring boot jpa dependency

Comment: I didnt understood what are you trying to put into cache. Please share the code for the classes you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved it for the moment. It turned out that the class org.w3c.dom.Document was causing the problem. It needed to much memory to deserialize from disk. SO when i increased the thread stack size (-xss2m) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Complete pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>GroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactID</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
              <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
              <version>2.10.6</version>
          </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm not using jpa. I just want to cache some service classes.